# How to save Contact details in the phone's address book from any application

Tags: android, save, addressbook

I am trying to create an application which will add contact details like phone number, email address and name in the phone's address book, but I have not idea how to do this. I know that we can access the contact details from the address book, but how can we add any new contacts from our application to the address book?

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

under Example: Inserting a Phone Number

**Update/Edit:**

Above mentioned url isn't valid anymore. I guess this page is the most relevant now:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

Comment: The URL isn't valid anymore, so I edited the answer and put a new, relevant url there.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it, android contacts are read only.

Edit: Actually it looks like you can modify and create new contacts. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

Comment: Ah, you are right. I misread the first part under insert. "A contact cannot be created explicitly" http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html sorry for the confusion.