# Vcard sent as plain text

Tags: android, sms, vcf-vcard

I have generated a vcard of the selected contact. I am sending it through sms (though i know we could send it through mms, but there are some phones that dont support mms).

when I am sending it to another phone, the exact string is received as such,

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Mahajan;Sahil;;;
FN:Sahil Mahajan
TEL;HOME:964-695-7130
EMAIL;HOME:sahilmahajanmj@gmail.com
END:VCARD
```

But I want that on receiving this message, there should be a default option of saving it as contact.

I am sending it using the following code,

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(mobileNumber, null, vCardString, null, null);
```

here vCardString is the actual string containing the vcard. Let me know, if i need to post anything else.

Comment: Did you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665359/how-to-save-contact-details-in-the-phones-address-book-from-any-application

Comment: more on this is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075694/inserting-contacts-in-android-2-2

Comment: I want to send vcard message to any phone(it could be even nokia).